# Access a managed C++ lib from regular C++

Tags: visual-c++, managed-c++

I am trying to call a method in a managed C++ library from a regular (unmamanged) C++ file. [I'm working from the example here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp) (which is really good except for this little issue).

My managed C++ code is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void ShowMessageBox(int *value)
{
    AutoTagManagedBridge::Class1 work;
    work.ShowCSharpMessageBox(value);
}
```

My unmanaged C++ code is:

```
_declspec(dllexport) void ShowMessageBox(int *value);
// ...
ACCB1 void ACCB2 MyPluginCommand(void *clientData)
{

    int val = 5;
    int *result = &val;

    ShowMessageBox(result);
// ...
```

In the unmanaged C++ project, I set the managed C++ project as a reference. However, when I compile I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   ShowMessageBox(int *)" (?ShowMessageBox@@YAXPAH@Z) referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl MyPluginCommand(void *)"
>   (?MyPluginCommand@@YAXPAX@Z)  BasicPlugin C:\src\AdobePlugin\win32\BasicPlugin.obj    1

And when I look at the link command the managed C++ module (AutoTagManagedBridge.lib) is not listed:

> /OUT:"Debug/BasicPlugin.api" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
>   /PDB:".\Debug/BasicPlugin.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "odbc32.lib"
>   "odbccp32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
>   "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
>   "uuid.lib" /IMPLIB:".\Debug/BasicPlugin.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86
>   /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL /PGD:".\Debug\BasicPlugin.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:".\Debug\BasicPlugin.api.intermediate.manifest"
>   /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. In order for VisualStudio to recognize a .lib file from the Managed C++, you need to set on your UnManaged project right click and Properties -> ConfigurationProperties -> Linker -> Input -> 
Additional Dependencies - > "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\ManagedDll.lib".